# OS X: are any shells started before I open the Terminal?

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, terminal, shell

On OS X, I'm trying to understand the whole concept of shells. Specifically, when I log onto the computer but don't start up a Terminal, has a shell started? Does it then start up a different kind of shell when I do open the Terminal? I know that before I've opened the Terminal, I'm logged into the computer as a given user, so I don't understand the difference between getting logged in when I turn on the computer, and getting logged in when I open the Terminal.

Can anyone provide any insight on all this?

Comment: You can use the Activity Monitor to confirm, but it is my understand that a "shell" (as UNIX/Linux people would recognize it) is only launched inside a Terminal (or in other tools that launch shells, including IDE's).  There is an environment for your user that is maintained by the OS (or the Finder?), but it's not a regular shell.

Comment: Do you mean "CLI shells"? In general ["shell" is a broader term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_(computing)), it includes shells with GUI.

Answer (score 0):

---disclaimer: not an apple user---

A shell is a program that interprets a series of commands. Those commands can come from the STDIN (standard input) or from a file. For example: if you start a `bash` without arguments, the STDIN will be your keyboard (this is a simplification). You can also use re-direction to provide the STDIN, for example:

```
echo 'echo konijn` | bash
```

But you can also us a file for the input. For example: if `file.sh` contains

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'wiep`
```

you can start a shell with this script explicitly:

```
bash file.sh
```

or, if the file  has been made executable, implicitly:

```
./file.sh
```

Next questions would be: what starts the script? On OS X you may start a script with the `launchd`, or in a crontab, once again explicitly or implicitly.

So, what happens if we start a terminal?

Your window manager will start the terminal. Your terminal will start the shell to which you talk. The terminal is there just to facilitate your interaction with the shell.

What helped me to understand what is happening is to determine what process starts what, with STDIN and STDOUT to where. Use `ps -ef` to determine the parents of the processes.